# Call to undefined function, changes on helper.php file but still cant call presentPrice function

Tags: php, laravel

in my view file I try to add this code, but cant call the function name '**present price**'

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>RM {{presentPrice(session()->get('coupon')['name'])}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

this function I add it into the app/helper path

```
<?php
   class helpers{
    function presentPrice($price)
   {
    return money_format('$%i', $price / 100);
   }
}
```

of course I have to run composer dump-autoload. But it still show me undefined function

Comment: Have you defined Helper Class

Comment: may I know where to defined it? Because I think view file can't defined 'use helper' ?

Comment: answered please go through it.

Answer (score 2):

You have put it inside a class . If you want to define helper functions you should:

Change your helpers source to:

```
<?php
function presentPrice($price) {
    return money_format('$%i', $price / 100);
}
```

Then add this to your composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
         "app/helper.php"
    ],
    keep the rest of the autoload parts as is
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload` again. This should make the file `app/helper.php` load automatically every time. (If the file is in a different path then update accordingly)

This will make `presentPrice()` available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Helper file

> /app/Helpers/Helper.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Helpers;
class Helper{
    public static function MoneyFormat($number){}
}
```

> /config/app.php

define alias

```
'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,
```

> /app/Http/Controllers/YourController.php

```
use Helper;
```

and use it where ever you want like

```
Helper::MoneyFormat($price)
```

Comment: it show the error undefined class error when i define alias.

Comment: Have you created helper file /app/Helpers/Helper.php updated my answer

Comment: my path is here ---> app/helpers.php